# Modify Java Source Code File and add some lines of code

Tags: java

I have a java source file (For Example)

```
public class JTest{  
  public static void main (String arg[])  
    { . . . . . }  
  public mytestmethod()  
    {  
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)  
      System.out.println(i);  
    }    }
```

what i have to do is to **write java program** that can **modify source code** of the above java file, Not the compiled class file.
after the modification using that program, the output may be . . .

```
public class JTest{  
  public static void main (String arg[])  
    { . . . . . }  
  public mytestmethod()  
    {  
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)  
      {                                    // { added to code  
         System.out.println(i);  
         System.out.println("ITERATION");  //new line added to code  
      }                                    // } added to code  
 }  }
```

i think my question would be clear now. it is just an example of my task.
which java library/libraries could be used.

**JAVASSIST** is helpful to modify the class file. it is a very easy and handy tool for bytecode editing but i have to edit the source code.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble? What does your own attempt at it look like?

Comment: i have used string.split method , stringtokenizer etc.

Comment: but it makes my task difficult. i just have to modify the body of some methods in any given java source code and generate new source code file which can later be compiled

Comment: Please show code that you have tried. We can not help if we do not know what you are doing.

Comment: @MattClark my code is not complete yet. i am trying different methods like split method, tokenizer etc to do it. but what i actually have to do is to find a specific method, then edit some specific lines of code in it. there are tools available like **JAVASSIST** etc but i need to modify the source code not the bytecode

Comment: Show what you have tried... We are glad to assist people with their code, but only if they _show_ a genuine attempt towards their goal, and give us something to work off of, we are not going to jsut come up with random pieces of code that may or may not suit your needs, because we do not know exactly what the OP intends on ^.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you will have to do a full syntax analysis. Java source code is essentially free form text, you cannot rely on line breaks or spacing beeing there, comments can be inserted at any place in the code. So all attempts to tackle that with string matching or regular expressions will eventually fail.

Tools like Javacc or antlr may be helpful for the parsing. If you search you will find Java grammars for these tools.

Comment: thanks. but i actually dont have to insert comments. i just added comments for clarification. i just have to insert code

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution (without full parsing using javacc or something similar):

create tagging comments such as

```
public void myMethod(bla blubb) {
//$myMethod entry$
stuff.going.on();
//$myMethod exit$
}
```

then use a simple string replace to inject your code. (keep markers after injection to be able to re-inject).

Doing a full syntax tree parsing and then inject code + rewrite the file keeping comments and formatting is a pretty complex task. You'll need some time for that.